# How to write a Regexp for any character, but it must be the same a specific number of times

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find strings that are the same character multiple times in a row. These can be any character (including the NULL char), so I cannot specify which character it is, but it occurs 20 or more times in a row.

The dot "." matches any character, but how do I specify in a RegExp, that it must be the same character if I don't know which beforehand?

Example:
Bla bla blub oooooooooooooooooo must be in the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx string.

I want to find the o-s and x-s lines. ".{10,}" matches any line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture a letter and then use back-reference 9 times to check if same letter is repeated 10 times:

```
/([A-Za-z])\1{9,}/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ5bV4/1)

**PS:** To check of any character use:

```
/(.)\1{9,}/g
```